# Extracting winrar unlimited file size till disk is full

Tags: archive, rar

When using the default archive manager ([image: pictogram of the default archive manager for ubuntu]) and trying to extract small files (< 1mB) the files keep getting bigger and bigger until the disk is full. What I mean by this is it keeps extracting and the extracted file keeps growing.

So if I try to extract a 100 kB file it starts at 1 gB and ends up at 80 gB.

Normal zips work fine.

My system:

- Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- GNOME 3.36.8

Comment: The question is totally unclear. Are you using Ubuntu? Which version? What do you mean by "files getting bigger"? Why are you using winrar? Is it installed using wine?

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, sorry. Its indeed a vague question. I will add my system and try to clarify. I will attach such a rar file soon.

Comment: for me this sound to be something like a zip bomb https://www.bamsoftware.com/hacks/zipbomb/ perhaps the default achive manager handles thhat zip bomb differently than the cli tool?

Comment: @AlexOnLinux Okay, thank you. What can I do about it? I read about it and its not malicious at all so its probably just a defect. On windows all is fine.

Comment: @laurent-dhont I don't know. Perhaps not extract it? A zip bomb is malicious. Its intention is to fill up your disk and render your OS unusable. What should that zip file contain that a 100kb file becomes as giant as 80gb? Even a word list would be bigger than 100kb. Especially if it grows unpacked beyond 80GB.

Comment: @AlexOnLinux I am very certain it is not malicious. Its just a file from a colleague and on windows there is no problem with extracting it. I now also tried with just random winrar files and its the same problem.

Comment: Sorry I have no clue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answer suggested installing and using `xextractor` which is not available on `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`. For me just installing `unrar` package solved the problem:

```bsh
sudo apt install unrar
```

Then try again, it worked for me.

Comment: Archive Manager and/or nautilus file explorer must be restarted before this works.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue with the default file manager on Ubuntu 20.04 and a RAR file that was certainly not malicious.

I fixed it by using another RAR extractor, the one I used was xextractor :

```
sudo apt-get install xextractor rar unrar
```

Once installed you can simply open up xextractor from the application list, open up your archive and extract it ! I imagine it would work with other archive managers as well.